# Rows are being deleted after fetch on from @ElementCollection

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, spring-data

I have created an `Entity` called Media with a list of tags that relate to the `Media`. I use `@ElementCollection` to save the tags. I have annotated it according to this post The problem is when I reading the field I get the content on the first time, but than it is being deleted.

I created a Repository:

**MRepo:**

```
public interface MRepo extends CrudRepository<Media, String> {}
```

And the delete happens when I am using the service to fetch the media:

```
...    
@Autowired
    MediasRepository mediasRepository;

    public MediaReadEvent findMedia(String mediaID){
    Media media = mediasRepository.findOne(mediaID);
...
```

**Hibernate SQL Log:**

```
hibernate: select tags0_.media_name as media_na1_2_0_, tags0_.tag_name as tag_name2_12_0_, tags0_.tags_ORDER as tags_ORD3_0_ from media_tags tags0_ where tags0_.media_nam
?
hibernate: delete from media_tags where media_name=?
hibernate: select tags0_.media_name as media_na1_2_0_, tags0_.tag_name as tag_name2_12_0_, tags0_.tags_ORDER as tags_ORD3_0_ from media_tags tags0_ where tags0_.media_nam
?
hibernate: delete from media_tags where media_name=?
hibernate: select tags0_.media_name as media_na1_2_0_, tags0_.tag_name as tag_name2_12_0_, tags0_.tags_ORDER as tags_ORD3_0_ from media_tags tags0_ where tags0_.media_nam
?
hibernate: delete from media_tags where media_name=?
```

**Media Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class Media {
  @Id
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "mediaid")
  private String mediaId;
  ...
//    @NotNull
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(
            name="media_tags",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="media_name")
    )
    @Column(name="tag_name")
    @OrderColumn
    private List<String> tags;


  public List<String> getTags() {
    return tags;
  }

  public void setTags(List<String> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
  }
  ...
}
```

Just in case it matters, I am using:
postgresql - 9.2-1003-jdbc4
spring-data-jpa - 1.5.1.RELEASE
spring - 3.2.8.RELEASE

Comment: Which code causes the SQL logs you posted? What are you doing?

Comment: @JBNizet Hey, I added the requested information. Let me know if something else is missing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any solution? I seem to be having the same problem.

maybe [this question and answer is helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569563/hibernate-enum-elementcollection-deleted-after-initialization).

I found that the same problem I was having seems to have disappeared after updating to from version 4.2.7 (Redhat) to version 4.3.1.Final-redhat-1.  I was also using the ENABLE_LAZY_LOAD_NO_TRANS feature.

Comment: Could not get it fixed so I created entities instead.

Comment: I just edited that I updated the version and the test case I had seems to be working, though I need to do more testing.